# How to write date object into implicit converter?

Tags: postgresql, date, slick, implicit-conversion, slick-3.0

I have a scala class with function named `getUser` which take a `year` & `month`. I am going to fetch a list of users with `year` & `month` based on `birthday` column which is defined as `Instant`.

I am using `postgresql` & `slick`. I wrote a sql like as:-

`sql"SELECT * FROM user_info WHERE birthday::text LIKE '1990-07%'".as[Seq[User]]`

For the above query I have also declare an implicit converter as follows:-

```
implicit val getUserResult = GetResult[User](r => User(r.<<, r.<<, r.<<, r.<<, r.<<))
```

I have written the corresponding code for the above query

```
case class User(id: Option[Int],
                name: String,
                birthday: Instant,
                updated: Option[Instant]) extends GenericEntity {
       def this(name: String,
                birthday: Instant) = this(None, name, birthday, None, None)
}

class UserTable(tag: Tag) extends GenericTable[User](tag, "user_info") {
      override def id = column[Option[Int]]("id", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)
      def name = column[String]("name")
      def birthday = column[Instant]("birthday")

  def * = (id, name, birthday, created, updated) <> ((User.apply _).tupled, User.unapply)
}

object Users extends GenericService[User, UserTable] {
      override val table = TableQuery[UserTable]

      override def copyEntityFields(entity: User, id: Option[Int], created: Option[Instant], updated: Option[Instant]): User = {
        entity.copy(id = id, created = created, updated = updated)
      }

      implicit val getUserResult = GetResult[User](r => User(r.<<, r.<<, r.<<, r.<<, r.<<))

      def userTable = "user_info"

      def getUsers(year: Int, month: Int) = {
        var monthString = month.toString
        if (month < 10)
          monthString = "0" + month.toString
        val yearMonth = year + "-" + monthString
        val sql = sql"SELECT * FROM #$userTable WHERE birthday::text LIKE '#$yearMonth%'".as[User]
        db.run(sql)
      }
}
```

When I am going to execute the query it introduces an error like (indicating with `^`, that is the problem will introduce while it is trying to convert `birthday`):-

```
diverging implicit expansion for type slick.jdbc.GetResult[T1]
starting with object GetIntOption in object GetResult
implicit val getUserResult = GetResult[User](r => User(r.<<, r.<<, r.<<, r.<<, r.<<))
                                                                   ^
```

Let me know, how can I overcome the above problem?